# Problema com funções do math.h

Tags: c

sempre recebo como resultado: 0.000000

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()

{

   float x1, y1, x2, y2, resultado;

   printf("insira x1:");
   scanf("%f", &x1);
   printf("insira y1:");
   scanf("%f", &y1);
   printf("insira x2:");
   scanf("%f", &x2);
   printf("insira y2:");
   scanf("%f", &y2);

   resultado = sqrtf((powf((x2 - x1), 2)) + (powf((y2 - y1), 2)));

   printf("resultado:");
   printf("%f\n", &resultado);

   printf("pressione qualquer tecla para sair.");
   getch();

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: Objetivo: calcular a distância entre dois pontos no plano cartesiano

Comment: Este código pode compilar?

Comment: Edite sua pergunta ao invés de adicionar informações da mesma em comentários

Answer (score 7):

O calculo está correto, seu problema está justamente na hora de exibir o valor na tela. Ao compilar o código tenho o seguinte warning:

> `a.c`: In function `main`:
>   `a.c:22:4`: **warning**: format `%f` expects argument of type `double`, but argument 2 has type `float *` [`-Wformat=`]
>
> ```
> printf("%f\n", &resultado);
>     ^
> ```

Dois erros claros aqui.

1. A função não espera um ponteiro para o valor, e sim o próprio valor. Use `resultado` no lugar de `&resultado`.
2. O formato `%f` recebe um `double`, não um `float` no `printf` (repare que no `scanf` ele de fato recebe um `float`). Use:

   ```
   printf("%f\n", (double)resultado);
   ```

   Ou, melhor ainda, declare todas as suas variáveis `double` e use `%lf` no `scanf`.

Sempre compile com warnings ligados!

Answer (score 0):

Parece que o código tem alguns problemas básicos. Que tal?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()

{

    float x1, y1, x2, y2, resultado;

    printf("insira x1:");
    scanf("%f", &x1);
    printf("insira y1:");
    scanf("%f", &y1);
    printf("insira x2:");
    scanf("%f", &x2);
    printf("insira y2:");
    scanf("%f", &y2);

    resultado = sqrtf((powf((x2 - x1), 2)) + (powf((y2 - y1), 2)));

    printf("resultado:");
    printf("%f\n", resultado);  // aqui

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: oq vc mudou no código? poderia explicar oq foi e pq agora deve funcionar?

Comment: Guilherme Bernal tem realmente explicou isso muito bem :-) `%f` espera um `float`, e `resultado` era um ponteiro para um `float`. O `getch` também foi depreciado com o meu compilador.
Guilherme Bernal aponta o cast para o `double`. Isto é muito importante, porque `double` ter uma precisão mais fina. Depende do que você quer fazer, mas é preciso ter cuidado.